# Can I use Python Peewee with sshtunnel?

Tags: python, ssh, peewee

I've tried to use Peewee with sshtunnel to connect to a remote mysql db:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         ('server.pt', 9922),
         ssh_password="pass_ssh",
         ssh_username="user_ssh",
         remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)) as server:
            myDB = pw.MySQLDatabase("dbname", user="db_user", passwd="db_pass")
```

But I get an error

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to include the local port that you've bound the tunnel to from the `server` object:

`myDb = pw.MySQLDatabase("dbname", host="localhost", port=server.local_bind_port, user="db_user", passwd="db_pass")`

See [here](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-3) for an example.

Comment: How would you reuse the ssh tunnel connection? every time a Peewee object is called a new ssh tunnel is established, on multiprocessing scenarios, it's overloaading the ssh server.

Comment: See also this discussion on PeeWee issues: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1674 . I particularly like this comment from "coleifer" (the father of PeeWee): "Why you would ever want to pipe a db connection over SSH is a whole other question."